# Paypal Smart Checkout | Multiple Payment Buttons with DIFFERENT currencies

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am working on a Paypal Smart button integration. On the marketplace it is for, a buyer can put items from various sellers in his cart. So there could be 2 items of seller "A" and 5 items of seller "B". The currency used by those sellers could be totally different.

The issue I am facing: When including the JS-SDK, I have to set the currency in URL of the SDK which means: I can not change it once loaded which renders my whole cart concept useless.

Is there a way where I could have different currencies for different pay buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possible (with async loading) to make a late decision about which currency SDK to load and then render some button(s) for that particular currency, it's not possible to render buttons for multiple currencies simultaneously within the same actual page/window.

To show buttons for different currencies simultaneously on the same 'page' , each block of currency buttons would need to be its own iframe, with its own currency SDK url for that frame's same-currency buttons.

Comment: Ahh, that's too bad. Surely enough, I can code "around" this limit, but it's a real pain for market places where anybody can sell to/buy from anybody.